# php set client side new path

Tags: php, path, include, require

i have used http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php **set include path** to set new parent folder to include php files.
Now , after i seted the new parent file , i want to include CSS files. how ever to include css files i need to use the old parent folder path to include it.

for example: my folders goes this way > oldParent/newParent/%files

```
href="newParent/CssFile.css"
```

and php files goes this way:

```
file.php
```

as you can see , set_include_path affect on PHP files path way , but how can i control css path files also?

Comment: CSS uses href , include PATH is strictly file system ..am not sure where you have conflict because this are 2 different things

Answer (score 1):

PHP couldn't care less about your web assets, unless you are attempting to inject them all into your HTML and generate a huge single-document monster. As far as I know, your question is not even related to PHP. PHP is a **server-side** technology—once the generated HTML leaves the server, the browser has no way to know how your HTML was made.

In HTML, you insert external assets like images, scripts or style sheets using specific HTML tags that expect a URL with the (public) location of the linked file. That's often unrelated to paths on the server's disk.